# Binding List<T> to Datagridview when DGV has specific column types

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to Populate a DGV from a List.  The Datagridview is editable and has specific column types specified.  i.e. Textbox, Combobox, Checkbox.

If I take the DGV.Datasource = MyList it adds all the properties of my T to the DGV **after** the specified columns. (*e.g. Address1, County, City, ID, Address1, County, City*)

```
Addresses = New List(Of Address)

    Dim a1 = New Address(Guid.NewGuid())
    a1.Address1 = "Address 1"
    a1.County = "County Test"
    a1.City = "My City"

    Addresses.Add(a1)

    Dim a2 = New Address(Guid.NewGuid())
    a2.Address1 = "Address 1"
    a2.County = "County Test"
    a2.City = "My City"

    Addresses.Add(a2)

    Dim a3 = New Address(Guid.NewGuid())
    a3.Address1 = "Address 1"
    a3.County = "County Test"
    a3.City = "My City"

    Addresses.Add(a3)
    uxAddresses.DataSource = Addresses
```

If I loop through, like below, it sets the first row fine but not row 2 or 3(in my Test Object).

```
Private Sub DataGridViewPaint(ByVal la As List(Of Address),
                              ByVal paramDgv As DataGridView)
    Dim intDr As Integer = 0

    For Each g In la
        paramDgv.Rows(intDr).Cells("ID").Value = g.Id
        paramDgv.Rows(intDr).Cells("Address1").Value = g.Address1
        paramDgv.Rows(intDr).Cells("County").Value = g.County
        paramDgv.Rows(intDr).Cells("City").Value = g.City
        intDr += 1
    Next
End Sub
```

This made me wonder, what's the proper way to accomplish this as I feel like I'm missing something here.... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to add a list to a grid view one row at a time.  you can just bind the whole list to the grid view, like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="False"
  AutoGenerateColumns="false" BackColor="White" 
  BorderWidth="2px" BorderStyle="Solid"
  CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="both" 
  EmptyDataText="No Log Messages">

     <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
     <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
     <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
     <Columns>                                  
       <asp:TemplateField Visible="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="ID" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="white">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="Server" Text=' <%#Eval("ID")%>' />
             </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>  
<asp:TemplateField Visible="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Address" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="white">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblAddress" runat="Server" Text=' <%#Eval("Address1")%>' />
             </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>                   
     </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Then just bind the source:

```
 Addresses = New List(Of Address)
'file the list

me.GridView1.dataSource = Addresses 
me.GridView1.DataBind()
```

Just make sure that your code in the client side gridview: <%#Eval("Address1")%>
matches the names of the properties in your list of objects.

Comment: Appologies, I forgot to specify that this is a winforms app.  So I do not have a `.DataBind()` available.  Thanks though.

Comment: What happens if you just me.GridView1.dataSource without databind?  Does that work?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [`DataGridViewColumn.DataPropertyName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname.aspx) property like so:

```
Column1.DataPropertyName = "Address1"
Column2.DataPropertyName = "County"
Column3.DataPropertyName = "City"
Column4.DataPropertyName = "ID"
```

And then afterwards, set `DGV.Datasource = MyList`.

Additional note: you need to set every column's `DataPropertyName` field otherwise you may end up with duplicate columns.

Comment: This actually works like a charm, except that I am still getting the duplicate/extra columns.  Not every column is duplicated and it shows them after the columns I specified in the Designer

Comment: @RefractedPaladin: Make sure you set the `DGV.DataSource` **after** you set the `DataPropertyName` for each column. Otherwise, I believe the symptoms you mentioned will appear.

Comment: I did.  It goes away if I specify every Property to a Column.

Comment: @RefractedPaladin: Good catch... I've updated my answer based on the comments in case anyone else stumbles across this. Thanks.